# Accepting JSONP request from mobile decives only

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, jsonp

I have a web application(php/wordpress) that serves data. I have a phonegap app which hits my webservices and gets a response. I have had to use JSONP and add these response headers as below for the device to recieve the data from my server without a Access-Origin error. I feel as if this is not secure and is an incorrect way to send this data. How can i only allow users on mobile devices to get this data? With this set up a user from anywhere could $_GET request anything from my service. My service does check for a login.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept ');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 10');
header("Content-type: application/javascript ");
```

Comment: If you authorize the client ("...check for a login"), then why does it matter who or what the client is?

Comment: Checking login status seems sufficient to me. Anyone can spoof a mobile device anyway, with a browser plugin

Comment: That is true, as long as the user is logged in it shouldn't matter what they are on. Maybes its my lack of confidence in mobile development but i did not believe i was sending data correctly. @arkascha

Comment: @RobGudgeon Ok. That does make sense i guess i just didn't trust that i was doing it correctly.